# Conditional Formatting based on if(sum<>0)-statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I've got a lot of if(sum)-Statements in my worksheet and would like to know if it is possible to give a condtional formatting based on my if-statement.

For example the if functions are looking like this:

```
=IF(SUM(I24:I960;I965:I1065;I1067;I1069;I1071;I1073;I1075;I1077;I1079:I1129;I1131:I1240;I1242;I1244;I1246;I1248;I1250;I1252;I1253:I2046)<>0;1;0)
```

and I would like to color the elements red, which makes the Statement "true".

I already did this manually by copying the cell areas in the conditional formatting, but it seems like Excel has restrictions concerning the space of the formular. Because of this problem, I have to start all over again every time this happens. Thats why I'm asking you for help. Maybe you can give me some insight on this.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You might just want to place this formula in a cell and apply your conditional formatting according to the value in that specific cell.

For example if you put your formula in cell A1 you might use this formula for your conditional formatting:

```
=$A$1=1
```

And assign the format you want. You can assign this conditional formatting to any cells you like to be formatted according to your formula.

Comment: Wow thanks! Never thought about this option. My Problem here is that the worksheet already uses a lot of different conditional formatting (design) and I would destroy everything with this.

Comment: does this colour the cells that make up the formula as in op, not the result?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do with CF, you could do using the precedents

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Precedents.Count > 0 Then
           If Target.Value = 1 Then
             Target.Precedents.Interior.Color = vbRed
           Else
             Target.Precedents.Interior.Color = vbGreen
           End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that the event `Worksheet_Change` is not called for the target cell if the formula's result value changes. It is only called if a cell is changed manually (or programmatically by a macro). So if I have a formula in A1 like `=A2` and i change the value in A2, the `Worksheet_Change` event is only called for `Target = A2` and not for A1 (even if the value in A1 changed too)